# React JS "onChange" function not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an `onChange`-event on an input listening for when `target.value` is greater than 0 to enable classes to then display a button.

This works on desktop however, not functional on iPad Safari - I'm unsure why?

Note I am using styled components and `PDInput` is declared as an input.

```
const PDInput = styled.input`
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f5;
    padding: 8px 0;
    padding-left: ${props => props.amount ? "15px" : "0"};
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0c2074;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 24px;

    &::placeholder {
        color: #0c2074;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
`

const updateRef = e => {
    if(e.target.value > 0) {
        setRef(true);
    } else {
        setRef(false);
    }
}


<PDInput type="text" placeholder="E.G Rent" onChange={(e) => updateRef(e)} />
```

Comment: Can you explain what "not functional" means specifically? Are you able to log from inside the `updateRef` function? Or does it not even get called? Are your conditions passing/failing as expected just without a state update?

Comment: State gets updated correctly as I'm listening for the e.target.value. When setRef is set to true there is a button that should display on screen. This works on desktop as expected but not on iPad safari. Everything works as expected on desktop.

Comment: You should debug iPad with safari logging. Logs may be more useful. Follow this link for debugging https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798

Comment: Can you show the source for PDInput?

Comment: @programmer updated

Comment: If the state is updating as expected, it doesnt seem like the issue is with this input. More likely elseware in the component.

Comment: @BrianThompson I have the safari debugger open with console open and added logs to each function. When I input values the logs show for desktop but do not for ipad debugger - can only assume it's onChange not supported?

Comment: onchange is pretty [globally supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange). So that seems unlikely

Comment: Try it with a plain input and see if it works. Maybe this has something to do with styled components.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution - the issue was that e.target.value isn't technically > 0. It returns false. You want to check if the e.target.value !== ''.

Code:

```
const updateRef = e => {
        if(e.target.value > 0 || e.target.value !== '') {
            setRef(true);
        } else {
            setRef(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not as **DRY** as it *could* be. Try `setRef(e.target.value > 0 || e.target.value !== '')`. **But** both `0` *and* `''` are falsey values, so can further simplify to `setRef(!!e.target.value)` using boolean coercion.

Comment: @DrewReese DRY? I'd pick the solution above because of readability over your suggested ones.

Comment: @goto1 I have to agree with Drew though, when I read `if(booleanStatement){set(true)}else{set(false)}` I'm thinking why all the extra fluff? Just do `set(booleanStatement)`. Not sure if we should take coding readability advice from someone who names himself **goto** though (just kidding Tom).

Comment: @HRM then I'd just create an extra variable, i.e. `const isValidRef = (...); setRef(isValidRef);` rather than using `setRef(!!e.target.value)` - not everyone will immediately know what the `!!` is doing here.

Comment: So why did it work on desktop? What's with the difference in behavior between desktop and ipad?